Algebraic Geometry book for someone interested in Differential Geometry
I am very interested in differential geometry. However, in order to broaden my horizons, I would like to know the connection between algebraic geometry and differential geometry, any recommendations for books or some details would be appreciated.

Maybe Jet Nestruev, Smooth Manifolds and Observables.

I think you should choose your book on algebraic geometry independently of your interest in differential geometry. The connections become much clearer if you already know more about algebraic geometry.

You might look at Griffiths and Harris. Also, take a look at their paper "Algebraic Geometry and Local Differential Geometry.".

@psl2Z This might be what I'm looking for. Thanks.

@Dietrich Burde Thanks for your advice.

@ Ted Shifrin It really helps me. Thanks.
